# Cached translations in CakePHP 3.7.4

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, translation, cakephp-3.x

I have taken over a project on cakephp.
The problem is that I can not change translation texts.
Under `src/Locale` I have:

```
en_EN
  default.mo
  default.po
no_NO
  default.mo
  default.po
cake.pot
default.pot
```

In controller

```
public function view($id)
{
    $order = $this->Order->get($id);
    $this->set(compact('order'))
}
```

In view I have a form where is translated text by default

```
 <?= $this->Form->control('email_message', [
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'rows' => 15,
            'help' => sprintf('Email will be sent to %s', h($order->contact_email)),
            'default' => __('pickup_mailtext')
        ]) ?>
```

No I have in

```
en_EN
  default.po
```

```
msgid "pickup_mailtext"
msgstr "This is the old pickup mailtext"
```

if I change it to

```
msgid "pickup_mailtext"
msgstr "This is the NEW pickup mailtext"
```

Nothing changes. I have deleted everything in persistent directory. 
Also in Config/app.php default language is set to no_NO, but as I mentioned before this string is under en_EN

under

```
no_NO
  default.po
```

There is:

```
msgid "pickup_mailtext"
msgstr ""
```

I have also noticed, tad this string is in

```
en_EN
  default.mo
```

but if I try to modify it I get Internal server error.

So my question is:
1. How to get this translation working? Why this string is not changing?
2. If the default language is set to no_NO, then why the translations is in en_EN and why it is getting translated instead of being empty?
3. How to clear those .mo files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.mo` files are the compiled binary versions of the respective `.po` files, you can't just modify them with a text editor, you need to recompile the `.po` files instead, using a program like [**`msgfmt`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Producing-Binary-MO-Files), or one with a GUI like [**Poedit**](https://poedit.net).

CakePHP will by default prefer `.mo` files over `.po` files (the former are usually faster to parse), ie if a `.mo` file exists it will be used instead of a possible `.po` file with the same name, so if you change only the `.po` file, nothing will happen as that file is not being used.

If changing the default locale in `config/app.php` has no effect, then the locale might get changed somewhere else in your app. Check `\Cake\I18n\I18n::getLocale()` in your view template to figure what locale is actually being used at that point, and set a breakpoint in `\Cake\I18n\I18n::setLocale()` (`vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/I18n.php`) or log a stacktrace to figure from where in the code the locale is being set.

Comment: If I do dd(I18n::getLocale()) I get beack "en_EN". Okay that is fine with me - lets say that locale is being set somewhere else but that does not explain the fact that if I make changes in en_EN -> default.po the text doesnt change. Also in the .mo file there is only this string. The rest of them is in the .po file

Comment: @Davis As mentioned, it's most likely because the `.po` file is not being used if a `.mo` file is present.

Comment: And how can I get rid of it?

Comment: @Davis Either recompile the `.po` files (preferred option), or delete the `.mo` files.

Comment: Thank you man! I did what you said and it worked! Marked as answer!